# How to create recordset w/ columns for previous 3 column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, "Results" w/ the following columns: `MatchDate`, `PlayerID` and `Score`

`SELECT * FROM Results WHERE PlayerID = 2 ORDER BY MatchDate DESC`

| MatchDate | PlayerID | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-11-25 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-11-21 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-11-20 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-10-05 | 2 | 2 |

What I'm trying to do is to build a query that creates the following resultset:

| MatchDate | PlayerID | Score | PreviousScore_1 | PreviousScore_2 | PreviousScore_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-11-25 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-11-21 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | null |
| 2021-11-20 | 2 | 1 | 2 | null | null |
| 2021-10-05 | 2 | 2 | null | null | null |

The above resultset contains the Score for the Player for the current data, as well as the latest 3 previous scores. `PreviousScore_1` = the Score for the previous MatchDate for the current player. `PreviousScore_2` = the Score for the second previous MatchDate for the current player, a.s.o.

I can't get my head around this. Is this even possible to achieve in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `LEAD` function as the following:

```
Select MatchDate, PlayerID, Score,
       LEAD(Score) Over (Partition By PlayerID Order By MatchDate DESC) AS PreviousScore_1,
       LEAD(Score, 2) Over (Partition By PlayerID Order By MatchDate DESC) AS PreviousScore_2,
       LEAD(Score, 3) Over (Partition By PlayerID Order By MatchDate DESC) AS PreviousScore_3
From Results
```

See a demo from [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22c1f51314402f3b1d98112409914c6f).